# Stripe php trying to add customers to plan[very simple]

Tags: php, stripe-payments

For some reason my code isn't working and i have no idea why. On Stripe i can see every log, but they are all POST/v1/tokens.

Here is my Index.php:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
<head>
   <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
   <title> Stripe Test </title>
 <form action="process.php" method="POST">
  <script
   src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" class="stripe-button"
   data-key="pk_test_MRCHJP8k2C6KajdgXeOu9TUA"
   data-amount="9000"
   data-name="Test"
   data-description="Shirt"
   data-image="https://stripe.com/img/documentation/checkout/marketplace.png"
   data-locale="auto"
   data-currency="cad">
  </script>
 </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is my process.php which doesn't really seem to be called and the code appears on page when submitting the stripe method:

```
<?php
 require_once('autoload.php');//empty php
\Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey("sk_test_bztUVzRlSqW2wWDVpXM6qNX4");
\Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey("sk_test_bztUVzRlSqW2wWDVpXM6qNX4");
\Stripe\Subscription::create(array(
   "customer" => "cus_BLVgYrfhMNVAi8",
      "items" => array(
       array(
      "plan" => "1month",//id
      ),
 ),
));
?>
```

Comment: `the code appears on page` means you do not have php installed/configured correctly.